# Unity : Keep gameobject in camera view no matter it's size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a little game where I generate rooms of different size and would like this randomly generated room to be always visible on the screen without caring about it's size. The camera is on a top view angle (rotation = 90,0,0).

I tried to create a relationship between it's size and the Y axis position of the camera to make it always visible but it wasn't successful. There is the solution where the object is kept on the bottom left corner of the screen but if the object is too big only a part of it is visible by the camera. I really have no more idea ^^

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It sounds like you were on the right track with changing the y-axis position - that is certainly one way to accomplish this. Another would be to change change the [Camera.orthographicSize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html) relative to the room size. Mess around with the relationship enough and either of these should work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using an Orthographic camera. For the Orthographic Camera, the size is the number of unity units from the center of the camera to the top/bottom of the screen. The width is then based on the aspect ratio. So, if you know how big the objects are that should be easy!

You can get or set the main camera size with `Camera.main.orthographicSize`

then get/set the aspect ratio (width/height) with `Camera.main.aspect`

and you can reset it after with `Camera.main.ResetAspect();`

Comment: Thank you a loooooooot to you two !
I didn't know about the orthographic camera and was searching for a solution for too long, thank you again and again :D